# How insert Airpush in widgets?

Tags: android, insert, widget, ads

I'm going to publish some widgets (they just show an image on the homepage), but I want to earn some cents, so I wish insert my Airpush codes.

How can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't use airpush - They are a scam - they never pay (to me and to 2 of my friends) or pay much less due to all sorts of reasons they make up.. (google it)

Answer (score 1):

Use below instructions :

follow the url to integrate Airpush in widget

http://wiki.airpush.com/index.php/Widget_apps

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Airpush airpush = new Airpush(getApplicationContext());
    airpush.startPushNotification(false);
    airpush.startIconAd();

    //Other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It inst possible, airpush only works with application on home and main screens, sorry